# Timestamp converting simpleDateFormat in Wrong Format

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I have read a csv file with timestamps in it in java.

```
String dat = "2016-11-29 12:05:55.0";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");// "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(dat);
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
```

> timestamp is now 2016-11-29 00:05:55.0

How can i change this? Why is 00 converted to 12?

Comment: `h` in the `SimpleDateFormat` is for `hours-of-am-pm`, so 1-12. You're looking for `H`.

Comment: If there’s any way you can (which there is), drop the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` and use the modern classes in `java.time`, including `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`. One of the good things about them is they will *force* you to use `HH` instead of `hh` and will not just give you an incorrect result and pretend all is well.

Comment: thank you very much for better option

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consult the docs for SimpleDateFormat: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

You will find that `HH` is Hour in day (0-23), and `hh` is Hour in day (1-12)